# How to switch column values into columns using reshape in r?

Tags: r, row, reshape2

I'm trying to reformat a dataframe that has four columns. However, one of the columns (dem_profile_description) has ~20 variables that I would like to change into columns. I downloaded the reshape package.

The first few lines of my dataframe is this:

```
dem_profile_field dem_profile_description dem_profile_data  Community
 dpsf0010042      Female 10 to 14 years(1)  4               Gnar
 dpsf0010043      Female 15 to 19 years(2) 20               Yoke
 dpsf0010044      Female 20 to 24 years(3) 22               Law
 dpsf0010045      Female 25 to 29 years(4) 23               Law
 dpsf0010046      Female 30 to 34 years(5) 24               Ark
 dpsf0010047      Female 35 to 39 years(6) 30              Riverland
```

I want this:

```
dem_profile_field Community (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6)
 dpsf0010042      Gnar      4
 dpsf0010043      Yoke          20    
 dpsf0010044      Law                    5   5
 dpsf0010046      Ark                        24
 dpsf0010047      Riverland                      30
```

My code is this:

```
library(reshape2)
census3 <- dcast(census2, "dem_profile_field" + "Community" ~ 
"dem_profile_description", value.var = "dem_profile_data" )
```

But I end up with this:

```
dem_profile_field Community dem_profile_description
1                 Community        2
```

Comment: What happens if you leave out all those double-quote marks in the formula?

Comment: @42- I get this error: Error in value.var %in% names(data) : object 'dem_profile_data' not found

Comment: Why does row 4 have two 5's in it?

Comment: @MikeH.Sorry I will edit that out now. Since their field numbers are different they should each have a separate row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically there - you just need to exclude the quotations on the `formula` call in `dcast` (you still need them for the `value.var`):

```
census3 <- dcast(census2, dem_profile_field + Community ~ 
                     dem_profile_description, value.var = "dem_profile_data" )
```

To get the names you want you can also do:

```
names_to_replace <- grepl("(\\(.*\\))", names(census3))
names(census3)[names_to_replace] <- str_extract(names(census3)[names_to_replace], "\\(.*\\)")
```

Comment: No problem, just edited my code so you can get the names the way you want

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting out with a new package for transposing data, you might want to take a look at tidyr instead. The syntax is more straightforward and it combines well with other data manipulation packages in the 'tidyverse'.

Your example would work like this

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(dem_profile_field = 
             c("dpsf0010042",
             "dpsf0010043",
             "dpsf0010044",
             "dpsf0010045",
             "dpsf0010046",
             "dpsf0010047"),
             dem_profile_description = 
             c("Female 10 to 14 years(1)",
             "Female 15 to 19 years(2)",
             "Female 20 to 24 years(3)",
             "Female 25 to 29 years(4)",
             "Female 30 to 34 years(5)",
             "Female 35 to 39 years(6)"),
             dem_profile_data = 
             c(4,
             20,
             22,
             23,
             24,
             30),
             Community = 
             c("Gnar",
             "Yoke",
             "Law",
             "Law",
             "Ark",
             "Riverland"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_transposed <- df %>%
    spread(dem_profile_description, dem_profile_data)
```